# Prove $\Vert T(x,y)\Vert\leq \Vert T\Vert\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be an operator defined on $X\times Y$, the product of normed space $X$ and $Y$ such that

(1) $T(x+x',y+y')=T(x,y)+T(x,y')+T(x',y)+T(x',y')$, $\forall (x,y)\in X\times Y, (x',y')\in X\times Y$.

(2) $T(\alpha x,\beta y)=\alpha\beta T(x,y), \forall (x,y)\in X\times Y$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being scalars, i.e. $T$ is bilinear.

Let

$$\Vert T\Vert = \sup\limits_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1, \Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\vert T(x,y)\vert.$$

Show that $\|T(x,y)\| \leq \Vert T\Vert\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert$.

I don't have an idea to prove it. I don't have an idea to modifying $\|T(x,y)\|$ such that get $\|T(x,y)\| \leq \Vert T\Vert\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert$. Any hint to prove it?

Comment: Is $T$ an operator that maps into the field or into any vector space ? if the latter is true then it should be
$$
\|T\|= \sup\limits_{\|x\|\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1}\| T(x,y)\|.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you exclude  the trivial cases ($x =0$ or $y=0$), then  for given $(x,y) \in X\times Y,$ with $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0,$ you can use the definition of the operator norm to estimate $$\left\| T\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}, \frac{y}{\|y\|} \right)\right\|.$$ Then use (2).